# Retrieving values in nested dict based on keys in a list

Tags: python

```
data = {"c":{"files":"s","d":{"files":["nothing"]}}}
positions = ["c","d","files"]
```

How can I get to position I have in list "positions"? I need to get from list "positions" something like this:

```
data["c"]["d"]["files"]
```

I also need to work with list which is on that position. I already tried something, but I couldn't work with that list in way I would want to.

```
def goto(data,positions):
    temp = data
    for i in positions:
        temp = temp[i]
```

Is there any cool way to do it?

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: There is nothing about JSON here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for `reduce`!

```
reduce(lambda a,b: a[b], positions, data)
```

If you're using Python 3, you'll need to import `reduce` like so:

```
from functools import reduce
```

In Python 2, it's a built-in function, and thus doesn't need importing.